# Using word embeddings as features in classification algorithms?

Tags: classification, nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, tfidf

I see there are ways to combine word vectors to form documents by taking averages or weighted averages. However, as a result of averaging there is a loss of information. Are there ways to retain the word embeddings of a document as is and use it as an input to a classification algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. Here are a couple of suggestions:

- Learn a weighted average of the vectors based on the classifier task. "[Task-Optimized Word Embeddings for Text Classification Representations](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fams.2019.00067/full)" by Grupta et al. goes into detail.
- Input each word embedding separately into the classifier.
- Train a new embedding model that embeds the entire document (e.g., doc2vec).

Comment: How can I input each word embedding separately into the classifier?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-3